# Does there exist a problem for which no existing solution can be parallelized on a Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines, parallel-computing

I'm asking for problems for which we know there exists a solution for which an equivalent parallel program *cannot* be written on a Turing machine.

Alternatively, have we proven the opposite to be true - that for *every* problem, there exists at least one parallelizable solution?

Comment: What is "the" definition  of *parallelisable*,  of *parallelisable algorithm*?

Comment: @greybeard: To answer your question strictly: "Able to be made parallel." Basically, what I'm wondering is: Given an infinite amount of resources, can we parallelize all solutions to EVERY solvable problem, or are there solutions that absolutely CANNOT be parallelized?

Comment: I think you're going to need to give us a clearer definition.  Any algorithm can be run on a parallel processor, e.g., by leaving all but one processor idle.

Comment: @D.W. OK. Here, a parallelizeable algorithm is one where at least one task within that algorithm can be split into asynchronous tasks. For example, a computer can calculate the sum of 1 and 1 by calculating 1 XOR 1, and 1 AND 1, and mushing those bits together. The first two tasks could be done asynchronously, so the algorithm is parallelizeable.

Comment: Again, I can always take any algorithm, and split it into two asynchronous tasks: the first task executes the algorithm, and the second executes a no-op.  I think you need a more careful definition of parallelizable.

Comment: @D.W. Let me give you an example of what I'm after. Presumably, you've loaded a dishwasher at some point in your life. What I've come to realize is that you can parallelize the process of loading a single dish into the dishwasher by breaking the dish into pieces and having multiple people take these pieces to the dishwasher. You have thus parallelized the process of loading a dish into the dishwasher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not precisely defined, so it's not really amenable to a precise technical answer at this stage.  But a common view/hypothesis/expectation is that there exist problems that are inherently sequential, in the sense that they cannot be substantially sped up on a parallel computer, no matter how many parallel processors you have.  A weak version of this view is implied by the conjecture that $NC \ne P$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_%28complexity%29), which is conjectured but not known to hold.  In particular, P-complete problems are good candidates for problems that don't benefit much from parallelization.  There are stronger versions of this view; for instance, in cryptography, timelock puzzles utilize functions that are believed to be inherently sequential: a parallel processor cannot speed them up very much.